# Selenium-side runner variable to output

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide, selenium-side-runner

Hello im using selenium side runner to get html table content into a variable using store text command then i print it with echo

what i want is to save the table stored text to .txt file for now im using powershell with " > example.txt" parameter like

```
Selenium-side-runner table.side > salida.txt
```

but isnt storing variable in the output just the selenium results

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`selenium-side-runner -c "browserName=firefox moz:firefoxOptions.args=[-headless]" project.side >> "result.txt"`
It's working fine

But `selenium-side-runner -c "browserName=firefox moz:firefoxOptions.args=[-headless]" project.side >> "result.txt" --"output directory='result' --output format='junit'"`
not working at all